# WPF MDI children

Tags: wpf, mdi

This question has been posted before, but I can't find a good answer.

I want MDI children in my WPF application. And I want those children to be fully WPF compliant.

.Net WPF doesn't have MDI children (windows within main window) any more. Some say it’s because the design is obsolete and GUI apps shouldn't be designed that way. Those people can refrain from answering this post. I know what I need. :)

What (preferably free) alternatives is there for WPF MDI?
Will they work with MVVM?

**EDIT:** PEOPLE - don't vote up comments that say "MDI IS NOT GOOD". I specifically asked people to avoid that. I'm asking for MDI windows, not to be told not to use MDI windows.

Comment: What's wrong with the answers to the questions you've seen posted before? Unless you tell us why those solutions won't work for you, people will be posting them again. For example: http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't remember what was wrong with it - but you make a good point, I should have been more specific. I'll get back to this as soon as I'm "in the code" again (some time next year).

Comment: Just tried MVVM light with WPF-MDI. I bound `Commands` in menu and button in MDI child (user control). It's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you don't want to hear that, but [MDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) basically aimed to duplicate the desktop metaphor inside the application's main window, and that was a little confusing to end users because it involved several levels of window management:

> **Tech:** Now click on the `Maximize` button of the active window inside the other window
> you've just restored to normal size and everything should be okay.
>
> **Customer:** What?

[Tab-based interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_%28GUI%29) are generally considered as a better alternative to MDI. You might want to use the [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx) class and read [Josh Smith's MVVM article on MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which demonstrates how to host your views in [TabItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx).

Comment: I do not disagree, but I do not agree. There are cases where we want MDI. Say for example a mIRC clone where everyone expects MDI window behaviour, and want to follow several channels at once. We can't leave it out because of a few bad uses.

Comment: @Tedd, I do agree that MDI still has its uses, but since WPF doesn't support that metaphor out of the box, it might be difficult to find an emulated solution that plays nice with MVVM...

Comment: Totally disagree, MDI is very useful in keeping many child Windows under control. Just look at the nightmare that is Photoshop CC - try Alt-tabbing to another app. Tabbed apps are Ok for somethings, but horrible for others. MDI should be treated like just another tool in the box, and not hated for reasons of fashion.